# Add side drawer to nativescript project with angular 2

Tags: angular, nativescript

I want to add side drawer to my project that be on the right of the page.
I followed the solution on the http://docs.telerik.com but it doesn't work for me.There is some bugs.
Here is my code :

app.component.html

```
          <!-- >> sidedrawer-getting-started-xml -->
<!-- >> sidedrawer-namespace-xml -->
<nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer id="sideDrawer">
  <nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>
    <StackLayout backgroundColor="gray">
      <StackLayout height="56" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: center;">
        <Label text="Navigation Menu"/>
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout>
        <Label text="Primary" padding="10" backgroundColor="lightgray"/>
        <Label text="Social" padding="10"/>
        <Label text="Promotions" padding="10" />
        <Label text="Labels" padding="10" backgroundColor="lightgray" />
        <Label text="Important" padding="10" />
        <Label text="Starred" padding="10" />
        <Label text="Sent Mail" padding="10" />
        <Label text="Drafts" padding="10" />
      </StackLayout>
      <Label text="Close Drawer" color="lightgray" padding="10" style="horizontal-align: center" tap="{{ onCloseDrawerTap }}"/>

    </StackLayout>
  </nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.drawerContent>

  <nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
    <StackLayout >
      <Label text="{{ mainContentText }}" textWrap="true" fontSize="13" padding="10" />

      <Button text="Open drawer" tap="{{ onOpenDrawerTap }}" margin="10" style="horizontal-align: left" />

    </StackLayout>
  </nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
</nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer>
<!-- << sidedrawer-getting-started-xml -->
```

app.component.ts

```
   import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import viewModelModule = require("./getting-started-model");
import frame = require("ui/frame");
import drawerModule = require("nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer");
import observableModule = require("data/observable");


// >> sidedrawer-getting-started-model
export class GettingStartedViewModel extends observableModule.Observable {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.set("mainContentText", "SideDrawer for NativeScript can be easily setup in the XML definition of your page by defining main- and drawer-content. The component"
            + " has a default transition and position and also exposes notifications related to changes in its state. Swipe from left to open side drawer.");
    }

    public onOpenDrawerTap() {
        let sideDrawer: drawerModule.RadSideDrawer = <drawerModule.RadSideDrawer>( frame.topmost().getViewById("sideDrawer"));
        sideDrawer.showDrawer();
    }

    public onCloseDrawerTap() {
        let sideDrawer: drawerModule.RadSideDrawer = <drawerModule.RadSideDrawer>( frame.topmost().getViewById("sideDrawer"));
        sideDrawer.closeDrawer();
    }
}

export class DataItem {
    constructor(public itemDesc: string) {}
}

@Component({
    selector: "tab-view-test",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {
    drawer :GettingStartedViewModel;
     opendrawer() : void{
         this.drawer.onOpenDrawerTap();
     }

}

   export function pageLoaded(args) {
    console.log("Page loaded");
    var page = args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new viewModelModule.GettingStartedViewModel();
}
```

app.module.ts

```
 import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule } from 'nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer/angular'

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NativeScriptModule, NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

The bug is here:

```
Error calling module function

Error calling module function

Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer/angular", relative to: app/tns_modules/
   com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:159)
   com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:60)
   com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
   com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:580)
   com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:574)
   com.tns.NativeScriptApplication.onCreate(NativeScriptApplication.java:17)
   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4728)
   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:148)
   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5478)
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
File: "<unknown>, line: 1, column: 265
```

Screenshot :

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are hitting multiple issues with your code.
The error suggests that you might be using incompatible versions. As there was just a new release of nativeScript 3.0.0 which has introduced some breaking changes you should verify that you are using the correct compatible version of **nativescript-telerik-ui-pro**

As of this very moment, these are the compatible versions:

```
fdr NativeScript 3.0.0 - use nativescript-telerik-ui-pro 2.0.1
fdr NativeScript 2.5.x - use nativescript-telerik-ui-pro 1.6.1
```

Another issue that I see in your code is that you are using the syntax for a non-Angular application (where the namespaces are imported in the XML files e.g.  `nsDrawer:RadSideDrawer`). However, in Angular the syntax is different. The best approach is to take a look at the getting started examples for side drawer in Angular [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/tree/release/sdkAngular/app/sidedrawer/getting-started)

e.g.
***getting-started.component.html***

```
<RadSideDrawer tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton>
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
        <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
            <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout class="sideStackLayout">
            <Label text="Primary" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Social" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Promotions" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Labels" class="sideLabel sideLightGrayLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Important" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Starred" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Sent Mail" class="sideLabel"></Label>
            <Label text="Drafts" class="sideLabel"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <Button text="Close Drawer" (tap)="onCloseDrawerTap()"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout tkMainContent>
        <Label [text]="mainContentText" textWrap="true" class="drawerContentText"></Label>
        <Button text="OPEN DRAWER" (tap)="openDrawer()" class="drawerContentButton"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

Note that we are using directly **RadSideDrawer** instead of namespaces.

and then in the Component file

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "ui/page";
import { ActionItem } from "ui/action-bar";
import { Observable } from "data/observable";
import { RadSideDrawerComponent, SideDrawerType } from "nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer/angular";
import { RadSideDrawer } from 'nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "tk-sidedrawer-getting-started",
    templateUrl: 'getting-started.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['getting-started.component.css']
})
export class SideDrawerGettingStartedComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
    private _mainContentText: string;

    constructor(private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    @ViewChild(RadSideDrawerComponent) public drawerComponent: RadSideDrawerComponent;
    private drawer: RadSideDrawer;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.drawer = this.drawerComponent.sideDrawer;
        this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.mainContentText = "SideDrawer for NativeScript can be easily setup in the HTML definition of your page by defining tkDrawerContent and tkMainContent. The component has a default transition and position and also exposes notifications related to changes in its state. Swipe from left to open side drawer.";
    }

    get mainContentText() {
        return this._mainContentText;
    }

    set mainContentText(value: string) {
        this._mainContentText = value;
    }

    public openDrawer() {
        this.drawer.showDrawer();
    }

    public onCloseDrawerTap() {
       this.drawer.closeDrawer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I followed your points,but still I have this bug.Also I put my screen shot after my question.Could you help me.                   Error calling module function

Error calling module function

Error: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "nativescript-telerik-ui-pro/sidedrawer/angular", relative to: app/tns_modules/
   com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:159)
   com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.java:60)
   com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Native Method)
   com.tns.Runtime.runModule(Runtime.java:580)
   com.tns.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:574)